# Dynamically set the number of columns in Primeface's dataGrid using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using Primefaces's dataGrid and want to dynamically set the number of columns, depending on client's screen width.

For that to implement, I use a script that uses jQuery's $(window).width() to detect the screen width, and then sends it as a request parameter. The script is called just before the dataGrid is rendered.

h:outputScript launches the method that receives request parameter and saves the number of columns in an ArrayList.

Then dataGrids column gets its value from an arrayList where all values are saved.

The problem I am facing is that the correct value is applied only from the additional page refresh. I understand that this is caused by JSF lifecycle and partial page load.

Please enlighten me where is my mistake, and what is best way to correct it.

Index.xhtml:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function win() {
            var width = $(window).width();
            $.post("index.xhtml", {windowWidth: width});
        }
    </script>
```

continued....

```
        <section id="main" class="col-lg-10 col-xs-6">
            <h:outputScript value="#{windowController.windowSize()}">win()</h:outputScript>
            <p:dataGrid value="#{productController.fullList}" 
                        var="p" 
                        paginator="true" 
                        rows="9" 
                        lazy="true" 
                        paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
                        rowsPerPageTemplate="3,9,15"
                        columns="#{windowController.lastFromList}"
                        id="dataGrid"
                        >
                <p:column>
                    <p:panel header="#{p.name}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{p.price}"/>
                    </p:panel>
                </p:column>   
            </p:dataGrid>
        </section>
```

WindowController

```
@Named
@SessionScoped


private int columns = 1;
private ArrayList<Integer> al;

public WindowController() {
    al = new ArrayList<>();
}

private void addToList(int i) {
    al.add(i);
}

public int getLastFromList() {
    if (!al.isEmpty()) {
        return al.get(al.size() - 1);
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

public void windowSize() {
    int width = 0;
    if ((FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("windowWidth")) != null) {
        width = Integer.parseInt(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("windowWidth"));
    } else {
        System.out.println("no param");
    }

    if (width > 1200) {
        addToList(3);
    } else if (width > 500 && width < 1199) {
        addToList(2);
    } else {
        addToList(1);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution:

I placed a Javascript into a login.xhtml page, simple page, not having multiple forms for evaluation, - it is not getting re-rendered several times, and the script gets the actual width at the first launch. So I just took its value and pass as a parameter to the bean, called by dataGrid's column.

That's it!